# Get the value from the selected button

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function, where when a user presses a button, a accordion with content goes down. Then a user is able to add a value from a textbox into the mysql db. But, I want the value fro the button to be added in the db aswell, which it does not right now. The value of the button (Day) is always empty.

All help is appriciated!

function:

```
var showDate = new Date();
var theForm = `<form class="" action="insertIntoCalendar.php" method="post"> 
                  <input id="day"type="hidden" name="day" value=""><br>
                  <input id="formInputPwd" type="text" name="message" value="" placeholder="Message"><br>
                  <input  id="formInputPwd" type="number" name="hours" value="" placeholder="Hours"><br>
                  <input id="btnCreateUser"  type="submit" name="" value="Send">
               </form>`;

function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");
    calendar.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        calendar.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
            var textarea = document.createElement("button");
            textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
            textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("id", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 );
            textarea.setAttribute("value", newdate + "-" + day1);
            textarea.innerHTML = day1; 
            var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
            textarea1.setAttribute("class", "content");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
            textarea1.innerHTML = theForm;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            var active = checkIfAnyVisible();
            if (active) {
                active.className = 'content';
                active.style.maxHeight = null;
            }

            if (content.style.maxHeight){
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
                content.className = 'content';
            } else if (!checkIfAnyVisible()) {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                content.style.width = "100%";
                content.className = 'content active';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "But, I want the value fro the button to be added in the db aswell, which it does not right now." you need to use AJAX to a server side programming language page which will insert the data into a MySQL database.

Comment: @RaymondNijland So im using php, and that does work. But what im trying to do is to be able to use the day value from the button in the day value of the form.